# JavaMail and Office 365

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, office365

I am trying to send email from server using JavaMail and smtp protocol. The email is name@mydomain.com. JavaMail is throwing the exception above and this message "Client does not have permissions to send as this sender ". Can someone tell me what to do? I have my email configured with 365 server.

```
 org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.office365.com:587
   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1421)
   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
   at ao.co.karrega.test.NEmail.main(NEmail.java:24)

 Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 
       550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2114)
   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1122)
   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411)
   ... 2 more
```

Comment: Does the "From" match the authenticated SMTP user?

Comment: Yes Sir. The from is one email account of my domain. Im using office 365. I can send email via office 365 but if I use javamail I got this exception

Comment: If you login as aaa@mydomain.com and try to send mail with a From header of bbb@mydomain.com, it's probably not going to let you unless you have special permission or unless you do something to convince it that aaa@mydomain.com is allowed to impersonate bbb@mydomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [here](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/56626), I'd suggest you try the following steps:

> In addition, SMTP relay in Office 365 need the following:
>
> • All the mailboxes must be license enabled Exchange Online mailbox, and cannot be shared mailboxes.
>
> • The SMTP set to port 587
>
> • Transport Layer Security (TLS) encryption enabled in the relay software
>
> • The mailbox server name must be correct.
>
> To obtain SMTP settings information, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Sign in to Outlook Web App.
> 2. Click Options, and then click See All Options.
> 3. Click Account, click My Account, and then in the Account Information area, click Settings for POP, IMAP, and SMTP access.

It might help if you could turn on Java-Mail debug and Systtem/Session properties in use for your code.